# UI patterns listed by type of UI design case

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, pattern-library

Most UI pattern libraries list patterns by UI element - e.g. *"footer UI patterns", "scroller UI patterns", "button UI patterns"*, etc.

Do you know a library where patterns are listed by design case - e.g. *"How to transform desktop hover content into mobile views, where hover does not exist"* or *"How to display a grid of boxes uniform in size, when each box would contain different volume of content"*, etc?

Comment: If you would create such library. What patterns would you put under "How to transform desktop hover content into mobile views, where hover does not exist"?

Comment: Are you looking for implementations of UI patterns? As the pattern is already in the question: "How to display a grid of boxes uniform in size, when each box would contain different volume of content" How is this different from a category for grid and/or box UI patterns?

Comment: @ jazZRo it could be put that way. If we have a category about "grid and/or box UI patterns", then we could have a section about UI design problems related to that category and then we could have the patterns which resolve those problems.

Comment: @jazZRo - about the hover problem - well, this deserves a whole new question opened :) My quick answer is that I have not come up with any good patterns to recommend.

Answer (score -1):

What you are referring to sounds more like a component library rather than actual UI patterns. To be fair, generally UI patterns are only suitable for mature or large design teams that need to manage a number of different brands and/or products.

If you look at a website like [UI-Patterns.com](http://ui-patterns.com/), the contents are organized by the type of problem or interaction that the user is dealing with and some of the reusable or repeatable patterns that have been implemented to solve the design task.

Take for example Getting input from the user, there are three different contexts that may require similar or different UI components.

[image]

There are plenty of other examples but I think better clarity of the terminology would help here since pattern is more generic and abstract than a UI component. Another example is the [Dark Patterns](https://www.darkpatterns.org/) website that lists a number of user interactions that use a combination of UI components.

Comment: I am speaking about patterns (not components) related to specific problems, not related to general interaction scenarios. For example "Getting input from the user" is a general interaction scenario. A specific problem would be "Elders are not likely provide input because of exaggerated privacy concerns". I am looking for a platform which lists such specific problems and provides patterns addressing those specific problems.

Comment: @drabsv The example that you give might not even be something that is solved by UX design, but something that is more to do with a holistic view of how users and services are designed and created to built trust. So it's hard to ask a broad question and expect a specific solution (and vice versa). This is why the example that I provided has the closest to what I think you are asking for.

Comment: "more to do with a holistic view of how users and services are designed and created to built trust" - this is by definition a matter of UX design :)